# The most efficient way to delete all duplicate rows from table?

Tags: mysql, duplicates, delete-row

I have a table:

```
| foo | bar |
+-----+-----+
| a   | abc |
| b   | def |
| c   | ghi |
| d   | jkl |
| a   | mno |
| e   | pqr |
| c   | stu |
| f   | vwx |
```

I want to delete **all** rows containing duplicates by `foo` column so that the table should look like this:

```
| foo | bar |
+-----+-----+
| b   | def |
| d   | jkl |
| e   | pqr |
| f   | vwx |
```

What is the *most efficient* way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can join a table from a subquery which returns only unique `foo` using `LEFT JOIN`. The rows that did not have a match on the subquery will be deleted as you desired, example

```
DELETE  a
FROM    TableName a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  foo
            FROM    TableName
            GROUP   BY Foo
            HAVING  COUNT(*) = 1
        ) b ON a.Foo = b.Foo
WHERE   b.Foo IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dff10/1)

For faster performance, add an index on column `Foo`.

```
ALTER TABLE tableName ADD INDEX(foo)
```

Comment: This works perfect but it's too slow (I have a very big table).

Comment: add an index on the column so it will perform faster, example, `ALTER TABLE tableName ADD INDEX(foo)` and see the performance.

Comment: Thanks but I've already done that. But it's the most fast way to do this, anyway, I see.

Answer (score 8):

Using `EXISTS`:

```
DELETE a
  FROM TableName a
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                 FROM TableName b
                WHERE b.foo = a.foo
             GROUP BY b.foo
               HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Using `IN`:

```
DELETE a
  FROM TableName a
 WHERE a.foo IN (SELECT b.foo
                   FROM TableName b
               GROUP BY b.foo
                 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Comment: If I am correct the exists version you have written here is significantly faster than the in version. With this in mind, is there any argument for the in version?